# ConnectDeleteEntity event doesn't work in World Plugin

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I want to make a world plugin with events callback, everything work perfectly except the ConnectDeleteEntity event.
With the following code, when we create a model, we get a "Add" message (the function "OnAddEntity" is called) but when remove a model (for example, by selecting a model and pressing the Delete Key, or with the menu), the function "OnDeleteEntity" is not called.

```
    namespace gazebo{
        struct PluginGazebo : public WorldPlugin {      
            //----------------------------------
            event::ConnectionPtr DeleteEntityConnection;
            event::ConnectionPtr AddEntityConnection;
            //----------------------------------
            void OnDeleteEntity(const std::string str){
                std::cerr << "Delete " << str << std::endl;
            }
            //----------------------------------
            void OnAddEntity(const std::string str){
                std::cerr << "Add " << str << std::endl;
            }
            //----------------------------------
                virtual void Load(physics::WorldPtr _world, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf){
                //--
                    this->DeleteEntityConnection = event::Events::ConnectDeleteEntity(boost::bind(&PluginGazebo::OnDeleteEntity, this, _1)); 
                    this->AddEntityConnection = event::Events::ConnectAddEntity(boost::bind(&PluginGazebo::OnAddEntity, this, _1)); 
                }
        };

        GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(PluginGazebo)
    }
```

When OnDeleteEntity should be called ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15349/connectdeleteentity-event-doesn%27t-work-in-world-plugin/) by [Benoit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3032/benoit/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like the `deleteEntity` event is never being fired by Gazebo, which is a bug. I ticketed an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2171/delete-entity-event-is-never-called).

A workaround for now would be to subscribe to the `~/request` topic and check if `_msg->request() == "entity_delete"`, see an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/7a341084eb8a546d72595675e5e83471f19d64d8/plugins/events/SimEventsPlugin.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#SimEventsPlugin.cc-47).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3032/benoit/) on 2017-02-01**:
Your workaround works perpectly ! Thanks a lot.